# How to draw diamond in wpf GeometryModel3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

I am unable to draw the correct shape of diamond.

```
        0,1,0
    -1,0,-1 1,0,-1
    -1,0, 1 1,0, 1
        0,-1,0
```

This is my approach for the diamond top point (0 1 0) and bottom point (0 -1 0) and the a square in between at y = 0. and then connecting them all with `TriangleIndices`.

My Code:

```
<MeshGeometry3D x:Key="diamond"
                                Positions="
                                       0, 1, 0  
                                       -1, 0,-1    1, 0,-1
                                       -1, 0, 1    1, 0, 1
                                       -1, 0,-1   -1, 0, 1
                                        1, 0, 1    1, 0,-1
                                       0,-1, 0  
                                      "
                                TriangleIndices="
                                       0  1  2     0  3  4
                                       0  5  6     0  7  8
                                       9  1  2     9  3  4
                                       9  5  6     9  7  8
                                       1  2  3     4  5  6
                                       7  8  9     1  2  5
                                       5  6  8     1  2  4
                                       1  2  6     1  2  8
                                       5  6  7     1  5  6
                                       1  3  5     0  2  3
                                       " />
```

This is my final result for the image

[image]
[image]

As you can see not all triangles are drawn and I don't know why. I know I have added alot of TriangleIndices in the XAML properties but still there is no full diamond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many tries this worked. But I still don't understand one thing

Is 0 1 2 in the `TriangleIndices` same as 0 2 1?

```
<MeshGeometry3D x:Key="Diamond"
                                Positions="
                                       0, 1, 0  
                                      -1, 0,-1    1, 0,-1
                                      -1, 0, 1    1, 0, 1
                                       0,-1, 0  
                                      "
                                TriangleIndices="
                                       0 1 2, 0 3 1, 0 4 3, 0 2 4, 
                                       5 2 1, 5 1 3, 5 3 4, 5 4 2
                                       " />
```